Uri.EscapeDataString not working as expected in SQL Server
I have a NET48 console app to test escaping strings by doing, for example:
Console.WriteLine(Uri.EscapeDataString("*"));

The output is as expected: %2A.
I then use the same function in another NET48 class library that is added as a CLR assembly in SQL Server 2022. This is the function:
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None)]
[return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
public static SqlString UrlEncode([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] string url)
{
    return new SqlString(Uri.EscapeDataString(url));
}

The function is created pointing to the assembly:
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UrlEncode](@url [nvarchar](max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [SqlClrFunctions].[Utils].UrlEncode
GO

Running this query:
select dbo.UrlEncode('*')

The result is: *
This is obviously wrong. However I can't figure out why the same function is behaving differently.
Am I missing something here?

Are you sure that your SQL CLR project is targeting the correct version of .NET Framework? The behavior of System.Uri.EscapeDataString() changed in .NET Framework 4.5, sounds like you could be targeting something earlier.

What's the definition of UrlEncode? perhaps you forgot to actually make it point to the assembly

@siggemannen The function is pointing correctly. I created the function: CREATE FUNCTION... RETURNS... WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS EXTERNAL NAME...

Please edit clarifications into your question

@DaleK string corresponds to nvarchar automatically.
